# Google Maps waypoints not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So , I don't know what is wrong with this code , help needed.

I want the user to enter the start , waypoints and ending address.

```
var start = document.getElementById('start').value;

var way = document.getElementById('way').value;

var end = document.getElementById('end').value;


var request = 
     {

       origin: start,

       destination: end,

       waypoints: way,

       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

    };
```

..............................................................................

```
 <strong>Start:</strong>

  <input id="start" type="text" ></input>

  <strong>Waypoint:</strong>

  <input id="way" type="text" ></input>

  <strong>End:</strong>

  <input id="end" type="text" ></input>
```

Don't seem to understand where I am getting it wrong and thanks in advance for an explanation.

Comment: What activates these functions?  Do you have a submit button?  I don't see any function wrapped around the javascript code.

Comment: Yes there is a submit button , which onclick activates the javascript code . My problem is , however, the way I take the value of the waypoints , I have a feeling that it is not right .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waypoints are an array of [DirectionsWaypoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint) objects.  These objects contain a LatLng object or address string and a Boolean stopover property.

Try this:

```
var waypoints = [];

waypoints.push({
     location:document.getElementById('way').value,
     stopover:true // true by default. Technically this property is optional.
});
```

here is a [Google Sample App](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints) working with waypoints.

Answer (score 0):

`waypoints` should be an array per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest)

If you have only one, use

```
waypoints: [way],
```

to pass an array of a single element.

Comment: I did var way = []; way.push(document.getElementById('way').value); even then not working . By the way thanks for mentioning that waypoints is an array of elements .